# How can I dismiss DialogFragment in onStart() of the activity?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-dialogfragment

I want some behaviors like this:

When I make a request to the server, the progress dialog appears. when I get response or the user cancel the call(By pressing Home or Back button), the dialog disappears.

I'm currently using Retrofit for network and made some wrapper class for ease of use.

At first, I use callback to dismiss dialog, something like this:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseVO>() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseVO> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();

        if (loadingDialog != null && loadingDialog.isVisible()) {
            loadingDialog.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }
}
```

It worked for Back key, but did not help me when it comes to the Home button. so I decided to deal with it in my DialogFragment.

In onStop() method, I cancel the Retrofit call.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    call.cancel();
    Log.d("NetworkProgressDialog", "onStop called");
}
```

In onStart() method, I check for if the call is canceled and dismiss the dialog.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (call == null || call.isCanceled()) {
        Log.d("NetworkProgressDialog", "call is canceled. dismiss dialog.");
        dismiss();
    }
    Log.d("NetworkProgressDialog", "onStart called");
}
```

This seem to be worked, but If I press Home and re-open the app again, the Logcat says "onStart called" and no dialog displays. And when I press Back after that, onStop() is called.

So I just wondering If I can dismiss my dialog in onStart() or onPause(). If it is not possible, how can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: at onStart() method there is no dialog showing up ...why do you want to dismiss a dialog which is not showing ??

Comment: you want to show the dialog if the call is not cancelled ryt ?? `in onStart()` @Tura

Comment: @SantanuSur If I don't call dismiss() in onStart(), then the dialog is shown properly. and yes I want to show the dialog if the call is not canceled.

Comment: @SantanuSur when I call dismiss() in onStart(), the dialog is not showing, but It still receives hardware events. Maybe It is not showing but It is still alive somewhere I guess..

Comment: that means you are saying the call is getting cancelled every time ?? (you are dismissing the dialog if the the call is cancelled )

Comment: @SantanuSur Well, not every time but the call is canceled outside of the dialog and unexpectedly happens. Users can cancel the call by pressing the buttons. And I can cancel the call whenever I want. The thing is, dialog should not be shown to the user when someone cancel the call.

Comment: ok so whats your issue now ? i mean what do want and whats currently happening ??

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to dismiss my dialog inside its onStart() method,  because It is called when user can see it. The problem is that the user **can't see the dialog anymore, but it is not actually dismissed** so user can interact with it.

Comment: then just give an else part `if (! call.isCancelled()) dialog.show();`

Comment: I want to **DISMISS** the dialog, not SHOW it.

Comment: even if the call is not cancelled ?? anyway i have updated my answer please check ...remove the code from onStart(..) and if you wanna dismiss the dialog every time just check if dialog is not null then dismiss it.